# How does the Hard Drivin' game engine work?

Tags: atari, arcade

Hard Drivin' is a classic Atari video game released in the arcades and then ported to many home systems.

How does the game engine work? How is the world data handled, how is collision detection done etc? I'm asking for a general description of its internal workings.

Comment: Is the source code available

Comment: [This site](http://archives.museumofplay.org/repositories/3/archival_objects/19381) seems to have source code for Amiga, Atari, IBM, and Spectrum versions.

Comment: I have a recollection that Hard Drivin’ models each car as if it were a single tyre for physics purposes. If so then ground contact will be modelled as a single point and car orientation worked backwards from previous state + orientation of polygon the player is in contact with (if any); friction will act as per that single tyre. Damned if I can recall where I read that though.

Comment: @Tommy that's the kind of thing I'm interested in. It seems to do collision detection with many objects and in a fairly generic way e.g. to support the loops. The loops also imply it has a moderately complex physics simulation going on but they could be faked somehow.

Comment: @hippietrail such a shame they don't share them.